# Javascript Alert Boxes not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This is weird, The following line of javascript:

```
alert("test");
```

gives the following error in chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'alert' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function

It also breaks when using a prompt. Oddly it works in firefox. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not able to replicate this error when placing this command alone in a document and viewing it in Chrome.  Do you have any other scripts loading on the page?

Comment: was the popup blocker, better popup blocker for chromium. glad to be back on the right side of the sun!

Comment: Love the fact some many people jump down the poster's throat about being a bad developer. Show some love on VD [and hopefully not a VD.] :) End result was some other developer's poorly written plug-in that caused the bug. You can go rip that developer[s] a new one. lol

Comment: If you set a variable name to "alert" you can have this problem as well. var alert = $('<div class="alert">Nope</div>'); alert('Message'); // Error

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Do you have a another pop up blocker plug-in installed on Chrome? If you do, disable/remove it and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Good call. That was it. I installed better popup blocker for chromium cause last week and added an exception and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is your Javascript enabled in the Chrome options?
Other thing is any other js library included which might change default js behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

As epascarello said its because of popup blocker plugin and I faced this problem with my localhost websites and prompt method.
So i fixed it by adding my localhost url to popup blocker's whitelist: `http://localhost`