# alert, prompt... not working on local server (Tomcat)

Tags: javascript, tomcat, localhost, alert, prompt

I had tried to use alert, prompt and result:

- If I open html file (address bar: file:///C:/..../index.html), it worked, a dialog box appeared.
- If I place html file, javascript file at webapps folder of Tomcat, and open index.html via localhost:8080, it didn't work.

  *An error:* **Uncaught TypeError: Property 'alert' of object [object Window] is not a function**

Why and how to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Alert Boxes not working in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996394/javascript-alert-boxes-not-working-in-chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a  pop up blocker plug-in installed? If you do, disable/remove it and see if the error goes away.

OR

Somewhere in your code you overrode alert. Check for var alert = ... or some other kind of declaration like that. Also check for window.alert declarations.

Comment: Oh, yes. I make a mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I know. But in next 6 minutes. :)